# Pandas DataFrame subtract cross-section

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the data from a 3D-measurement (some 27k rows). I have already created a multi-index consisting of the 3 coordinate columns (x, y, z). The data looks like that (multiple xz-planes along the y-direction):

```
                                  Analog 1
Position Y Position X Position Z          
   y0         x0          z0       value0
   y0         x0          z1       value1
   y0         x0          z2       value2
   y0         x1          z0       value3
   y0         x1          z1       value4
   y0         x1          z2       value5
   y1         x0          z0       value6
   y1         x0          z1       value7
   y1         x0          z2       value8
   y1         x1          z0       value9
   y1         x1          z1       value10
   y1         x1          z2       value11
```

Here is an example: [sample data](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar0OA4ZjI7mWnFpJNmbjGqDJjWyL)

In the next step I want to subtract the values of the of the cross-section / slice at `y=y0` from every other xz-plane in order to normalize my data. Currently, I do that by looping over every row:

```
for row in data.itertuples():
    ind = row[0]
    value = row[1]
    ref = data["Analog 1"].ix[(y0, ind[1], ind[2])]
    data["Analog 1"].ix[ind] = value - ref
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Related question (actually using a multi-index: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67203888/2988730)

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier IMO to `reset_index` to restore the index values as columns and then call [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) to subtract all rows from the row of interest:

```
In [65]:
df = df.reset_index()
df.sub(df[df['Position Y'] == -27.0].iloc[0], axis=1)

Out[65]:
   Position Y  Position X  Position Z  Analog 1
0         0.0         0.0         0.0      0.00
1         0.5         0.0         0.0      0.00
2         1.0         0.0         0.0      0.00
3         1.5         0.0         0.0      0.00
4         2.0         0.0         0.0     -0.02
```

Note here that the filtering `df[df['Position Y'] == -27.0]` returns a `DataFrame` so if you try to subtract this it will just give you `NaN` for all other rows, so by indexing the first and only row using `iloc[0]` this returns a `Series` so it will broadcast along the full df.

If necessary you can set the index back afterwards:

```
In [80]:
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sub(df[df['Position Y'] == -27.0].iloc[0], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(df.columns[:3].tolist())
df

Out[80]:
                                  Analog 1
Position Y Position X Position Z          
0.0        0.0        0.0             0.00
0.5        0.0        0.0             0.00
1.0        0.0        0.0             0.00
1.5        0.0        0.0             0.00
2.0        0.0        0.0            -0.02
```

Comment: That would be an approach, if I have only one row with the index "Position Y" == -27. But I have many xz-planes along the y-direction. I have corrected the question to emphasize that.