# Compare one portion of dataframe to another with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a 3-level MultiIndex:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(18, 2)),
                      index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[True, False],
                                                        ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'],
                                                        ['one', 'two', 'three']],
                                                       names=['bool', 'ans', 'count']),
                      columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> df
                   A  B
bool  ans   count      
True  yes   one    5  0
            two    3  3
            three  7  9
      no    one    3  5
            two    2  4
            three  7  6
      maybe one    8  8
            two    1  6
            three  7  7
False yes   one    8  1
            two    5  9
            three  8  9
      no    one    4  3
            two    0  3
            three  5  0
      maybe one    2  3
            two    8  1
            three  3  3
```

My goal is to subtract off the `maybe` values from all the others with the same `bool` and `count`. The subtrahend is

```
>>> sub = df.loc[(slice(None), 'maybe', slice(None)), :]
>>> sub
                   A  B
bool  ans   count      
True  maybe one    8  8
            two    1  6
            three  7  7
False maybe one    2  3
            two    8  1
            three  3  3
```

The issue is that when I try to subtract this from the other items, the indices don't match up as expected:

```
>>> df - sub
                     A    B
bool  ans   count          
False maybe one    0.0  0.0
            three  0.0  0.0
            two    0.0  0.0
      no    one    NaN  NaN
            three  NaN  NaN
            two    NaN  NaN
      yes   one    NaN  NaN
            three  NaN  NaN
            two    NaN  NaN
True  maybe one    0.0  0.0
            three  0.0  0.0
            two    0.0  0.0
      no    one    NaN  NaN
            three  NaN  NaN
            two    NaN  NaN
      yes   one    NaN  NaN
            three  NaN  NaN
            two    NaN  NaN
```

The result I would like is

```
                   A   B
bool  ans   count
True  yes   one   -3  -8
            two    2  -3
            three  0   2
True  no    one   -5  -3
            two    1  -2
            three  0  -1
True  maybe one    0   0
            two    0   0
            three  0   0
False yes   one    6  -2
            two   -3   8
            three  5   6
False no    one    2   0
            two   -8   2
            three  2  -3
False maybe one    0   0
            two    0   0
            three  0   0
```

How to I tell pandas to honor `bool` and `count` levels but ignore the `ans` level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-section `xs` would probably be a good option here:

```
df.sub(
    df.xs('maybe', level=1)
).swaplevel().reindex(df.index)
```

Output:

```
                   A  B
bool  ans   count      
True  yes   one   -3 -8
            two    2 -3
            three  0  2
      no    one   -5 -3
            two    1 -2
            three  0 -1
      maybe one    0  0
            two    0  0
            three  0  0
False yes   one    6 -2
            two   -3  8
            three  5  6
      no    one    2  0
            two   -8  2
            three  2 -3
      maybe one    0  0
            two    0  0
            three  0  0
```

Comment: The more I play with this, the nicer it gets. Thanks.